# Error when pointing artifactory to artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory, artifacts

I have an instance of Artifactory installed locally. Within the instance, I am able to create references to other remote repositories.

Now, I have another instance of Artifactory, which exposes its own repository: *.../remoteArtifactory/repo*

I am trying to point to this repo in the first instance of Artifactory.

But in doing so, I have:

> Connection failed with exception: Circular redirect to
>   ".../remoteArtifactory/repo"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you, and fixed it by completely ignoring that error message and saving the repository. To reiterate:

1. Ensure you have the correct path to the remote repository, eg: `http://host:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/`
2. Click *Test*, and you'll get the `Connection failed with exception: Circular redirect to` - **Ignore this!**
3. Click *Save*

**Note:** different versions of Artifactory have slightly different paths/URLs. This caused me a little grief.

---

**Remote Repository Settings**
[image: Remote Repository Basic Settings]

[image: Remote Repository Advanced Settings]

I guess it's worth mentioning that I needed to specify the local proxy server (TdmsProxy).

Also, to confirm that you've got the correct path to the remote instance, check that you can receive a POM via the browser (or `wget`) from it, eg:

```
http://your-remote-repo:8080/artifactory/libs-releases-local/com/company/area/project/version/project-version.pom
```

Once, you've received the POM, just use the first part of the URL, eg:

```
http://your-remote-repo:8080/artifactory/libs-releases-local/
```

(I realise you've probably checked your path at least 10 times, but this bit me!)

Comment: Do you mean, you were anyway able to download artifacts locally deployed on the referred artifactory instance?

Comment: @Neel Yes. My situation is that there are two instances of Artifactory. One in my local network (repo A), and another in the corporate IT network (repo B). One of my projects POM file points only to repo A, but has a dependency on a library that's only in repo B. I configured a remote repository in repo A which points to repo B (this is what my answer refers to). I was able to resolve the dependency via: My PC -> Repo A -> Repo B.

Comment: does not work for me! :( Is there any switch in the target repo that we should flip to make it accessible / expose it as a maven repository?

Comment: @Neel Assuming you can retrieve files via your browser or `wget`, then I don't think there's anything you need to set on the remote repository. Also, I've updated the answer with a bit more info.